# Restart nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I try to `sudo service nginx restart` and it shows this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I think it is about this symlink?

```
ln -s ../sites-available/default default
```

I try

```
cd /etc/nginx && grep -R listen *

sites-available/default:        listen 80;
sites-enabled/default:        listen 80;
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The error means you already have a process on your server listening on TCP port 80. You should check what proceess is running and kill it if you do not need it. Then start nginx.

Comment: I try to kill but when I want to restart it I must kill it again. is this normal thing ? or it can fix ? sorry I'm new

Comment: What is the process that's using port 80? Is it nginx or something else? On your server, only one process can listen to a port so you will have to disable any other processes that are set up to claim port 80.

Comment: i grep -R listen * is sites-available/default: and sites-enabled/default:  is use

Comment: Use "ps -auxf" to see what processes are currently running on your server. Or use "netstat -tulpn" to see what processes are using what ports. That will let you find out what is taking up port 80 on your server. See this link for instructions on how to use "netstat": http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-network-connection-linux/

Comment: it return only tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   -

Comment: If you do "netstat -tulpn" you should get a list of processes and what is listening on the ports. The right most column should tell you the PID and the "Program" name. If you have something besides nginx listening then that process is causing nginx to fail. If nginx is the only process lisening on port 80, you may have something wrong with your configurations -- make sure you're not including the default nginx configurations multiple times.

Comment: I think that it about multiple time with symlink but it try to remove the default on sites-enable that is the symlink file but the problem is not gone. thank for helping me i'm trying to find the problem.

Answer (score 11):

You can kill it using:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

And then try restarting nginx again:

```
service nginx start
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) installed, which was running. Uninstalled it and the problem disappeared.